# TFS Build Template Customization ( MSBuildArguments)

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have to customize TFS DefaultTemplate.xaml with MSBuildArguments Parameter.
Once we try to create new XAML build definition & select default template, once it gets loaded then I want to set code MSBuildArguments in Advance setting & parameter should be `/p:DebugType=pdbOnly;Configuration=Release` by default.

As of now this Arguments we have to put manually whenever we create a new build definition. I want to make it customize this template.

screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Okay. Have you opened up the XAML build process template in Visual Studio and attempted to make the modification?

Comment: yes Daniel I opened the XAML build process template in VS & tried to make some changes in MSBUildArgument Variable Metadata & added one switch in activity but that didn't work as expected. Please help me out if you have any inputs..Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify MSBuild Arguments when create a build definition or queue a build is more convenient.

However if you want to bind the arguments with the xaml build template, then you need to custom the template.

In your scenario, you can simply replace the value of `CommandLineArguments` with below strings: (***Note*** that the arguments you added here will be hidden, that means you can not see them in build definition, they are set to be the default arguments)

`String.Format("/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true {0}", "/p:DebugType=pdbOnly;Configuration=Release")`.

But same time the `MSBuildArguments` you specified in build definition will not be available any more.

You can reference below articles to custom the build template to replace the MSBuildArguments:

- [Pass Relative Path Arguments to MSBuild in TFS2010 Team Build](https://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/pass-relative-path-arguments-to-msbuild-in-tfs2010-team-build/)
- [Properly incorporate MsBuild arguments into your build process
  template](https://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/07/properly-incorporate-msbuild-arguments.html)

[image]

Comment: @Dhurva Have you resolved the issue by the answer? any update?

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy for your suggestion, Still i didn't get a chance to work on this due to some highly critical item. Will let you know definitely once i'll try your solution. I believe  it should work in my case also..Thanks once again for your post..

Comment: @Andy-- thanks a lot for your post . It worked for me..Many thanks

Comment: @Andy--Done is it ok now?

Comment: @Dhurva Generally if the answer helps you could vote it up, if the answer not related to your question or guide to wrong direction, then you could vote it down, if the answer resolved your issue, then you could Mark it as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. :)